# ¿Cómo uno 2 variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Tengo un formulario en react el cual el `name` del `input` es dinámico, porque ese input se múltiplica cuantas veces quiera el usuario.

`item` es el indice de un array que se llena cuantas veces se múltiplique este input, entonces lo uso para indentificar cada input creado.

```
<label htmlFor='product'>
  <input
    type='text'
    name={`product_${item}`}
    placeholder='Producto'
    onChange={handleInputProduct}
  />
</label>
```

El name del input iría quedando así:

```
product_0: valor,
product_1: valor,
etc.
```

Lo que necesito es poder acceder al todos los valores que va creando, por ahora lo he intentado así:

```
console.log(`${form.product_}${item}`);
```

Pero me da undefined, si hago así:

```
console.log(form.product_0);
```

Si agarra un valor, obviamente solo del primer input, pero necesito que la forma de agarrar los valores también sea dinámica porque no sé cuantos input pueda haber.

Gracias, si no queda tan claro por favor avisenme!

Comment: De donde viene ese `item` ?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo haría es usar un Hook donde un ítem, y luego ir agregando más

```
  Const form = {name: 0, value: ''}
  Const [ item, setItem ] = useState([])

  Const addItem = () => {
     SetItem([...ítem, {name: ítem.length, value: ''])
  }

  Const handleInputs = e => {
      Const { name, value } = e.target
      Ítem.forEach((i)=>{
          If(i.name === name){
           I.value = value 
          }
         setItem(e => e.splice(ítem, 1) return [...item, i ])
       })
  }

  return(
    <Button onClick={addItem}>
        Add new item
    <Button/>
    {Ítem.map((ítem, i)=>(
      <Input onChange={handleInputs} name={i} value={ítem.value} />
     ))}
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear un array que iras llenando con un modelo de un objeto. Lo que haces cada vez que se aumenta un producto es duplicar el modelo del objeto e insertalo en el array.

```
const formulario = [];
```

Cada que duplique un formulario lo que haces es:

```
const modelo = {producto:'', referencia:''}
formulario.push(modelo)
```

Luego simplemente mapeas el array **formulario** con un bucle **each**. Si estás trabajando en react, haces algo similar, pero usando el **state**.